# In what domain can $\frac{1}{4}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^2$ be one-to-one function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Where is $\frac{1}{4}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^2$ an injective function?

I'm thinking about substituting $z=re^{i\theta}$, and I got that: 
[image]

Anyway, I have to choose an answer out of these domains:

1) ${Re(z)>0, Im(z)>0}$

2) ${|z|>4}$

3) ${\frac{1}{4}>|z|>0}$

4) ${|z|>\frac{1}{2}, Im(z)>0}$

5) ${2>|z|>1}$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question in the title: $\dfrac14\Bigl(z+\dfrac1z\Bigr)^2$ is single-valued since it is a rational function of $z$.

Comment: the question implying that its single-valued only in the domain ${Re(z)>0,Im(z)>0}$ but I can't see that yet. its a complex function so I think that what makes the difference, maybe you're thinking about it as a function of real numbers. or I don't get your point.

Comment: "Single-valued" means that the function assigns exactly one output to each possible input. An example of something that is not single-valued is $\log(x)$ which assigns all of the values $\ldots, -2\pi i, 0, 2 \pi i, \ldots$ to the value of $\log(1)$.

Comment: There no ambiguity about calculating $f(z)$. Polynomial and rational functions are single-valued, as are $\mathrm e^z, \cos z,\sin z, sinh z$, &c. The situation is very different from $z^{1/2}$ or $\log z$.

Comment: ... based on your question and comment, I suspect that you mean "one-to-one", and are using the wrong term. (possibly via mistranslation to or from your native language.

Comment: I think the translation should be an injective function:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function

Comment: $f(1/z)=f(z)$ also $f(-z)=f(z)$ so if $z$ is in the domain then $-z$ is not also if $z$ is in the domain then $1/z$ is not.

Comment: "Injective" and "one-to-one" have the same meaning in English: if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$. However, "single valued" has a different meaning: $f(x)$ has only one value (which is part of the definition of a function).

Comment: @kingW3 this is applicabble on each different quadrant, so i can say that its one-to-one there ?

Comment: injectivity is not a local property so it doesn't make sense to ask "where" it is injective.

Comment: @mercio you're right, I re-phrased the question. it's an american question where u have to choose an answer out of many. so maybe this is why it didn't sound logical.

Comment: I think this is good problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of knowing why $\frac 14(z + \frac 1z)^2$ isn't one-to-one.

$f(z) = z + \frac 1z$ is not one to one because $f(z) = f(\frac 1z)$.

$g(u) = u^2$ is not one to one because $g(-u) = g(u)$.

So $\frac 14 g(f(z))$ is not one to one because $z, -z, \frac 1z, -\frac 1z$ all get mapped to the same value.

Note:  $\frac 1z = \frac {\overline z}{z\overline z} = \frac {\overline z}{|z|^2}$.

So we need a domain $D$ so that if $z \in D$ then neither $-z, \frac 1z,-\frac 1z$ are in $D$. [In general,  assuming $z\ne 0; z \ne \pm 1$]

1)If $Re(z) > 0; Im(z) > 0$ then $Re(-z) < 0; Im (-z) < 0$ so $-z$ is not in the domain.

If $Re(z) > 0$ then $Re(\overline z) = Re(z)$ and $Re(\frac 1z) = \frac {Re(z)}{|z|^2} > 0$.  If $Im(z) > 0$ then $Im(\overline z)=-Im(z) < 0$ and $Im {\frac 1z}= \frac {Im(\overline z)}{|z|^2} < 0$ so $\frac 1z $ is not in the domain.

This is a possibility for the domain.

2) If $|z| > 4$ then $|\frac 1z| < \frac 14$ and $\frac 1z$ is not in the domain.  But $|-z| = |z|$ so there is nothing restricting $-z$ from being in the domain if $z$ is.  So this domain fails.

3) fails for the exact same reason 2) fails.

4) If $Im (z) > 0$ then $Im(-z) < 0$ so $-z$ can not be in the domain.  If $|z| > \frac 12$ then $|\frac 1z| < 2$ so if $\frac 12 < |z| < 2$ then $\frac 1 z$ is in the domain.  This fails.

5) If $2 > |z| > 1$ then $2 > |-z| > 1$ so this domain fails.

So the answer is 1).

Comment: in the first option, why isn't $Im\frac{1}{z} <0$?

Comment: Because .... oops.  That's why.

Comment: In other words, that was a huge goof on my part.  Re(1/z) will have the same signage as R(z) but Im(1/z) will always have the opposite signage as Im(z).  Hence what I said earlier was quite false.